# como criar uma "lista de localStorage"?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Cada vez que o usuário clicasse no botão, gostaria que salvasse a informação num `localStorage` diferente e tentei fazer com `for`, e ir incrementando 1 a cada vez que clica no botão, tipo assim:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem('modeloProduto'+i, $('.divProdCarrinho').html());
    var teste = localStorage.getItem('modeloProduto');
}
```

então ficaria **modeloProduto1**, **modeloProduto2**, etc.

É possível?

Comment: sim é possível, mas, não do jeito que você está fazendo. A recuperação também não pode ser feito assim, qual é a razão disso ... um Carrinho de Compra?

Comment: Sim, esse o objetivo.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, também faço isso numa aplicação, porém você precisa salvar o índice no Local Storage:

```
let i = localStorage.getItem('index') || 0;
for(; i<10; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem('modeloProduto'+i, $('.divProdCarrinho').html());
}
localStorage.setItem('index', i);
```

No início da aplicação você deve pegar o valor do storage e atualizar ele quando mudar o valor da variável

Answer (score 0):

Como o localstotage se trata de um storage do tipo Key->Value, nao é possível criar um array nele, porém é possivel transformar o texto para JSON string e salvar ele. Depois, apenas dar o parse desse texto. Da seguinte forma:

```
var array = [];

function adicionar(dados) {

    var itemList = localStorage.getItem('nomeDoItem')
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nomeDoItem'))
        : [];

    itemList.push(dados);

    localStorage.setItem('nomeDoItem', JSON.stringfy(itemList);

}
```

Toda vez que o parse for realizado, o array terá os itens que foram adicionados no push